# Better way to add default html error message to custom validation in jquery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have been trying to add html error message to password field as below:

```js
$.validator.addMethod('passwordformattester', function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^(?=^.{8,15}$)((?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[\~\!\@\#\$\^\&\*\_\-\+\=\`\|\\\(\)\{\}\[\]\:\;\'\<\>\,\.\?\/?])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[\~\!\@\#\$\^\&\*\_\-\+\=\`\|\\\(\)\{\}\[\]\:\;\'\<\>\,\.\?\/?])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\~\!\@\#\$\^\&\*\_\-\+\=\`\|\\\(\)\{\}\[\]\:\;\'\<\>\,\.\?\/?]))^.*$/.test(value);
},'<ul><li>Password format invalid</li><li>Password format invalid</li><li>Password format invalid</li><ul>');

$("#example").validate({
  ignoreTitle: true,
  errorElement:'div',
  highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).parent().addClass('field-error');
  },
  unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).parent().removeClass('field-error');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="example">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" data-rule-passwordformattester="true"/>
  <input type="button" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: `data-rule-passwordformattester="true"` I am attaching it as data-rule. and its working as expected. I just need a better way instead of directly inserting html in addmethod

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation and looking at the examples?  You are correct, you should never have to put the HTML inside the message.  The options provided by the plugin would give you everything you need to accomplish this.  BTW, you never explained the goal... each message is a `li` inside a `ul`, or you want one `ul` at the top filled with `li` elements?